# Connecting in Toronto on different airlines

Tags: canada, short-connections, lufthansa, toronto, air-canada

I am about to order a flight to San Jose, Costa Rica from Tel Aviv. 
I am concerned that the connection in Toronto is too short. I have a 1:25 hour connection, arriving with Lufthansa and departing with Air Canada.

[image: Print screen from kayak]
Any thoughts? My google search didn't yield any useful info on different-airlines flights there.

Comment: Have you found whether you need to go through immigration? Or is your luggage labelled through to the final destination?

Comment: i checked in kate's online guide link, seems that i don't need to go through immigration. also, according to her the luggage will be labelled to the final destination - but i will ask about it in the airport just in case. thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The airport has a [handy online guide](https://www.torontopearson.com/en/connections/guide?arrivingairline=dlh&arrivingdestination=fra&departingairline=aca&departingdestination=sjo) for this. I filled out the form using the information from your question and you don't need to pick up your bags (get them tagged to SJO when you first check in) or go through immigration. You will use a kiosk and swipe your passport. You will not have to change terminals. All of this adds up to 1:25 being plenty of time, even if the incoming flight is slightly delayed.

Note that while you are changing airlines, they are in the same alliance, so they are very closely connected. Transferring luggage is more streamlined, you don't change terminals, and so on.

Comment: General warning about Toronto: some airlines will proudly proclaim over the PA system on landing that you do not need to pick up your bags if you are connecting. I learnt the hard way that _this is, at best, an oversimplification_ - I was changing terminals and _should_ have picked up my bags, despite not even changing airlines! I had similarly been informed earlier by desk staff that I didn't need to recheck. I thought it suspicious, but you do as you're told, right? Consequently my bags did not make it with me and I was without them for two weeks. Staff at home said this happens quite a lot.

Comment: (Doesn't appear to be in play here but _double check_.)

Comment: The oversimplification will be "if your bags are checked right through to the destination", something you arrange on departure. At some airports *regardless of what was done at departure* everyone must pick up their bags and take them through customs. Therefore the PA announcement is setting up a contrast. I will note that there are no airlines in YYZ using 2 terminals so if you were changing terminals, you were changing airlines. Anyway, the final word at YYZ is the tool linked to in the answer: use that and you won't go wrong.

Comment: It was a while ago, but I think it turned out to be a codeshare, so though the tickets were on the same airline (and indeed the same booking), the carrier was different, and that was the source of the problem and confusion. That tool looks good.